# The location service on the device is disabled [Flutter geolocator v6.1.4]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation

I am always getting that message when trying to get my current location. I am running my app on real device. I followed the documentation instructions here [geolocator plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator). At first it gets the location, then after quitting the app ang start it again,it says that

> The location service is on the device is disabled

Why I am getting that error even though I already enabled the location services?

```
class LocationController extends GetxController{

   var position = Position().obs;
   var lat = 0.00.obs;
   var long = 0.00.obs;
 Future getLocation() async {
   try{

       position.value = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

       lat.value = position.value.latitude;
       long.value = position.value.longitude;
     } catch (e){
       print(e);
     }
  }
}
```

Call...

`locationController.getLocation();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Download & Import Plugin**

[geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
```

**In your AndroidManifest add permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**initialize variable**

```
Position _currentPosition;
String _currentAddress = "";
```

**Current Location Function**

```
_getCurrentLocation() async {

    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
   //Pass the lat and long to the function
    _getAddressFromLatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

  });
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
  }
```

**_getAddressFromLatLng**

```
 _getAddressFromLatLng(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);

      Placemark place = p[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.locality}";
        print(_currentAddress);       
    
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

If above problem occurs just run `flutter clean` ,uninstall the app then restart the phone and run the project again

Comment: How to convert longituge and latitude into human readable address?

Answer (score 3):

You have most likely given the location "`permission`" but the service itself(the GPS service) is disabled.

The important thing to note is Permission is NOT the same as service being enabled. Your location permission could be ON but `GPS` might be off.

That's when you get this error log.
You can Geolocator plugin to first check the status of locationService using

```
await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
```

If this bool is false, you can request to turn ON the GPS service as

```
await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
```